easy HTTPS for Wordpress with Docker and Cloudflare Tunnels
I'm trying to host a Wordpress website on a Docker container on my Windows Server.
I use CloudFlare tunnels for making them available to anyone on the internet.
It works, but for some wordpress reasons, only using HTTP. I hosted other websites using other frameworks and they all work on HTTPS by default.
For some reason I can't make the Wordpress use HTTPS unless I set a SSL certificate, which I don't want!. I want a simple solution that doesn't require any manual config, any certificates that will expire, etc.
Any ideas?
